# Alternate Definition of a Derivative Question

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

The alternate form of the derivative is

> $$f'(a)=\lim_\limits{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$

Can this be rewritten to this and still be true?

> $$f'(a)=\lim_\limits{x \to a}\frac{f(a)-f(x)}{a-x}$$

If what I wrote violates any limit rule please tell me.

Comment: The term "alternate form" in your text (not in your title) is not adequate : it is the classical definition of the derivative ! It would be an "alternate form" if you had given at first another definition of the derivative... but which one ?

Comment: The bleepin' expressions are equal! End of proof.

Comment: @zhw., I think the OP has the right to be cautious. Not everything that seems equal is always so. For example, in general $\frac{dy}{dx} \neq \frac{1}{dx/dy}$. And that's exactly because of the limit operation

Comment: But $a/b = (-a)/(-b)$ is always true if $a,b \in \mathbb R, b \ne 0.$

Comment: @zhw., you did not consider the limit operation anywhere in this statement. And that's just the kind of reassurance the OP wanted. The rules of arithmetics may not hold under the limit in general

Comment: So you actually believe that if $u(x) \equiv v(x),$ the situations $\lim_{x\to a} u(x), \lim_{x\to a} v(x),$ can be different? I'm afraid in that case I must bid you adieu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. But you're not using any properties of limits. Notice that the fractions inside the limits are actually the same:

$$\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = \dfrac{-(-f(x)+f(a))}{-(-x+a)} = \dfrac{-1}{-1} \cdot \dfrac{f(a)-f(x)}{a-x} = \dfrac{f(a)-f(x)}{a-x}$$

Comment: Technical note: the fractions aren't the same, but their values are.

Comment: They are the "same" fraction. If you want a more technical word, they are "equivalent" fractions.

Comment: "Same" does not imply syntactic symbol for symbol sameness. For example, one can say $(1+1)/4$ and $2/4$ are both the same as $1/2$ even though all three use distinct lists of symbols.